# Inserting INTO XML Column shows nothing at all

Tags: xml, sql-server-2012

I am creating a table as explained here - [Why XML column is greyed out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25032601/why-xml-column-is-greyed-out)

Now I am trying to populate it by,

```
Declare @docy xml = N'<elements>..... 6000 character file </elements>'

SET IDENTITY_INSERT TableName ON 

INSERT TableName(Id, ID_A, ID_B, Xml) VALUES (3, 0, 0, @docy) 

SET IDENTITY_INSERT TableName OFF
```

but now all I can see is a record with id = 3, ID_A = 0 and ID_B=0 ***but xml = empty.....***

It worked yesterday, I came in morning and it was empty as well, so I started again and now it doesn't work.

Comment: What **datatype** did you use or your `@docy` variable??

Comment: @marc_s Also tried xml, it isn't making any different, xml column is still empty

Comment: This is probably a stupid question, but is that a typo in your INSERT statement?  @doc versus @docy?

Answer (score 0):

The field name for the `XML` could be better named, try `XmlData` for example.  Also, change your `insert` to:

```
INSERT TableName(Id, ID_A, ID_B, [Xml]) VALUES (3, 0, 0, @docy)
```

You have declared a variable `@docy` but you have `@doc` in the `INSERT`.